# Meteor.setInterval breaking after +1 day of uptime (callback: undefined)

Tags: meteor

we are experiencing `Exception in setInterval callback: undefined` for intervals after a few days of them running on an hourly basis. Restarting resolves it for a few days until it breaks like this again. What could be the cause of this?

(there is nothing else being logged/thrown, no stack trace either)

```
        Meteor.setInterval(
            startJob(),
            1000 * 60 * 60
        );
```

Meteor: 1.8.0.2

Comment: Can you please add the code for `startJob`? Maybe there is an error that is not shown on the console. Many Meteor functions are designed to handle their internal exceptions to prevent a total halt on the server (causing the whole app to crash) and maybe this one is just not "printing" the error.#

Comment: Hi @Jankapunkt the method is quite big and calling a bunch of other functions. All of those functions do not suppress any errors. While there are a couple of try/catch blocks, they always console.log the error.

Comment: Does this error occur on a shorter timeframe as well? If so it would be good to improve the answer to a more reproducible code so we can try on our machines, too.

Comment: It does not, it only happens after a good day of uptime.

Comment: I agree with Jankapunkt, this is almost definitely something inside `startJob`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Meteor.setInterval(startJob,1000 * 60 * 60);"?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the crash is that you are calling `setInterval` repeatedly. In the short term it's ok, but you end up with many interval timers running, and that is eventually going to be a problem because of the memory and processing load.

I prefer to use the npm package `node-cron`, I set up the timer in a startup method like this:

```
//
// These are cron-style time specifiers
//
//                       ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
//                       │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
//                       │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
//                       │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
//                       │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday)
//                       │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday on some systems)
//                       │ │ │ │ │
//                       │ │ │ │ │
//                       * * * * *

const TICKER_INTERVAL = '1,16,31,46 * * * *' // This runs 4 times an hour
// const TICKER_INTERVAL = '* * * * *' // This runs every minute (use when debugging)

Meteor.startup(() => {
  cron.schedule(TICKER_INTERVAL, Meteor.bindEnvironment(signoutTicker))
})
```

This only applies on the server of course (you knew that, didn't you?)

I find this works very reliably for me.